# Copying objects in an array before removing it

Tags: ruby, reference

The code below loops through an array `factor_list` and checks if each of them contains a specified variable. If so, remove them from the array, multiply them together, and sum out the final result with respect to the variable. After all the operations, add the factor back to the array.

```
temp_factor = nil
factor_list.each{|factor|
        if factor._variables.include?(variable)
            if temp_factor == nil
                temp_factor = factor
            else
                temp_factor = multiply(temp_factor, factor)
            end
            factor_list.delete(factor)
        end
    }
temp_factor = sumOut(temp_factor, variable)
factor_list << temp_factor
```

The problem is, `temp_factor` is always `nil` in every iteration, even if it has been set in a previous loop. I thought the main problem was because of the deletion in the array, so I removed the deletion for testing, and that solved the problem (but my array is full of trash of course). So I came to the conclusion that my `temp_factor` was a shallow copy of the object, and so its referencing object is gone with the original one. I then tried doing a deep copy using the marshal trick, but it didn't help.

That was all I have got, as I was unable to solve the problem. Can anyone help me identify the mechanism behind all these myths?

It's cool that you guys give very nice advice about rewriting the code to avoid problems, and they really help! But I'm still wondering what caused the above problem? It would be nice if I can learn that bit of information!

Comment: Is it correct that the first factor in the list will get multiplied with itself while the others won't, or is that a bug?

Comment: @Russell Sorry I don't see how the first factor is multiplied by its own? When it is the first factor, temp_factor will be nil and be assigned as factor, that's all. Until it finds another factor that satisfy the condition then they will be multiplied.

Comment: Yes, my bad, I misread it. I generally try to avoid ifs and especially nested ifs in my code for exactly this reason - they're easy to misread if you're not paying full attention!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

College years with C++ and STL had taught me hard: never ever modify a collection that you're iterating at the moment. So, instead of deleting items in place, why don't you try to build a new array?

```
temp_factor = nil
new_factors = factor_list.map do |factor|
  if factor._variables.include?(variable)
    if temp_factor == nil
      temp_factor = factor
    else
      temp_factor = multiply(temp_factor, factor)
    end
    nil
  else
    factor
  end
end.compact

temp_factor = sumOut(temp_factor, variable)
factor_list = new_factors + [temp_factor]
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm really not sure I understand what you're trying to achieve with the code, so it might help if you could give more of a description of what you want the end result to be and why, but based on what I *think* you're trying to do, I think you can get much greater clarity by splitting it into a few steps:

```
# first, split the array into an array that matches and one that doesn't
matched, factors = factor_list.partition { |f| f._variables.include? variable }

# then call multiply with each element of the matched list on the result of
# calling it on the previous elements
temp_factor = matched.reduce { |acc, f| multiply(acc, f) }

temp_factor = sumOut(temp_factor, variable)
factor_list = factors << temp_factor
```

I would also reconsider having so many temp variables that are frequently reassigned, as it becomes very difficult to keep track of what their values are at any point - and so very easy to introduce bugs.

Comment: Hmmm... Partitioning the array is a good call, I have never thought of it. Maybe it is a better solution after all. Except I don't really understand how the reduce part works. What is acc?

Comment: `acc` stands for accumclator - and `reduce` is just another name for `inject` if you've come across that? It basically iterates over the list, calling multiply with `acc` and the current element. On the first run, `acc` is set to the first element in the collection, but you can also provide a default value. On subsequent runs it is the result of multiply.

Comment: Thanks that's something new I've learnt. I'm very new to Ruby so this helps me a lot. But if I assume correctly the above code will multiply the first item with itself right?

Comment: No, it starts by multiplying the first two items, then multiplies the result with the third item, etc etc